# How to empty out a column

Tags: vim, replace

I'm searching to empty out multiple columns in VIM
(not to delete but to put spaces inside).

This is my search command:
 `/\%2c\|\%4c\|\%>5c\%<9c`
(column: 2,4,6-8)

How can I empty out these columns in vim?
`:%s/\%2c\|\%4c\|\%>5c\%<9c/ /g` doesn't work

Comment: N.B: You don't need to prefix all of your questions with `VIM: `. That's what StackOverflow's tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\%c` is a [zero-width match](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width).

You'll need to match something like:

```
/\v^(.).(.).(.)...
```

Which will keep the values of columns 1, 3, and 5 in groups.

Then you can substitute:

```
:%s!\v^(.).(.).(.)...!\1 \2 \3   !
```

...keeping columns 1, 3, and 5 but replacing the rest of the first eight columns with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use 'and' `.*` command:

```
:%s/\%>5c.*\%<9c\|\%>20c.*\%<30c/     /g
```